# In Spacemacs/Emacs, How to break one long string to shorter same width multiple lines string?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

Now:

```
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUpwmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ51s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQAB
```

Expected:

```
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0
FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUpwmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/
3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ51s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQAB
```

Only this one line is enough. Not require the whole document. What should I do?

Comment: You want to insert hard line breaks? Or just display this long line wrapped, without changing the value?

Comment: @Chris Insert breaks.

Answer (score 0):

One may achieve it using regular expressions:

In Spacemacs:

- mark the line using `V`
- `M-:` and enter `'<,'>s/\(.\{80\}\)/\1\n/g`, where 80 is the desired line width.

Or using Emacs's `replace-regexp` with `\(.\{80\}\)` as the regexp and `\1 RETURN` as a replacement (to insert the return character, use `C-q C-j` in this case)